# Problem with headlines

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a problem with headlines. My kode is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt.,leqno]{article}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO, LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

This makes the page number on the top and on the left. In command `\fancyhead{}` I am trying to write headline.
But when I do this I have two headers: one centered on the page and the other on the right. I want to have just one. And he has to have a font: \ scshape \ centering. I do not know how to do it.

Headline should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what information should go in the header and in what location?

Comment: Headline should be in the middle. Content for the headline are: ON THE ZEROES OF THE RIEMANN.

Comment: The option to `\documentclass` should be `11pt`, not `11pt.`. Then your MWE lacks `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`.

Comment: Will that always be the content? Is it the title of the document? Is it the title of a section?

Comment: So now how to DELETE the dot and I can delete this package? It is not the title of a section. This text is not dependent on the section.

Comment: Fancyhead package I need to order a page number on the right at the top (even numbers) or the left (the numbers do not even). Maybe you know an easier way?

Comment: So you probably do not need fancy at all.`\pagestyle{myheadings}` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are need different positioning for even and odd pages, you need the  `twoside` class option. To have a centered header, use `\fancyhead[C]{<contents>}`; there's no need to redefine `\footrulewidth`, since it's set to 0pt by default. To clear predefined fields, it's enough to use `\fancyhf{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\scriptsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{\scriptsize\MakeUppercase{On the Zeroes of the Riemann Zeta Function}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I gave the wrong type of font. Now, I checked that should be uppercase letters - all equal. Not like the first bigger than the rest.

Comment: @Kasia please see my updated answer.

Comment: just one moment

Comment: @Kasia please see my newly updated answer. Is is something like that what you want?

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UhpJs.jpg

Comment: @Kasia well, that's what my code produces.

Comment: Ideally. That's what I meant. Just how this compares size it probably should be a smaller font - just a little.

Comment: What is the name of the font smaller than small?

Comment: @Kasia please see, once again, my updated answer.

Comment: @Kasia the font switches (in decreasing order) are `\Huge`, `\huge`, `\LARGE`, `\Large`, `\large`, `\normalsize`, `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny`; choose the one that suits your needs.

Comment: Already selected ideal size. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Kasia you're welcome! I find somehow odd that you ended up accepting another answer that didn't have the required solution, but that's up to you :-)

Comment: This is my day first in this forum and I do not know what clicked. Of course, only your solution is good. Can I still go back to them click?

Comment: @Kasia of course you can, but please don't think I am forcing you to anything. You are the only one that decides which answer you consider to be the best one.

Comment: But I understand you, and I am surprised that I clicks, because just you have answered me.

Comment: @Kasia Please do it.  Gonzalo Medina is a real master.

Comment: But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina And at the end we will ask Kasia for her proof of Riemann Hypothesis. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke hehe! Indeed, I would love to see a proof.

Comment: If you want to know proof you must get a book :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO, LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textsc{On the zeroes of the Riemann}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: \fancyhead[CO]{\uppercase{On the zeroes of the Riemann}} make headlines with this text on the center but also the name of section on the right

Comment: No, when I compile this document, I only get the page number in the upper left and "On the zeroes of Riemann" in the upper centre. If you say section in the upper right, it seems, some other package inserts some information there. Please give a complete MWE in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the corrected 3 lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

And headline should be automatic (section etc.) or manually written?

Comment: manually written